# SmtpException in System.Net.Mail.dll

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

Im trying to send an email with c#, like so:

```
public string SendEmail(string employeeEmail, string clientEmail, string subject, string message)
{    
     MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(employeeEmail, clientEmail)
     {
          Subject = subject,
          Body = message,
          BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
          IsBodyHtml = true
     };

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
     NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.Credentials = basicCredential1;

     try
     {
          if (UserExists(employeeEmail))
          {
               if (objDAL.ClientExists(clientEmail))
               {
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                    return "Email sent";
               }
               else
               {
                    return "Client email not found";
               }
          }
          else
          {
               return "Employee email not found.";
          }
     }
     catch
     {
          return "ERROR";
     }
}
```

But it throws a 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.Net.Mail.dll in `client.Send(mailMessage);` and i have no idea why. I've been searching for an answer for a days...
Can someone please help me understand whats going on ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: Are you inside a corporate network with an outlook server? If so you cannot access your gmail account.  Try the code from home and see if it works.  Inside a corporate network all port 587 is send to the company email proxy server which will give an error if you are using your gmail account.

Comment: @jdweng No, im not in a corporate network, im home. And both employeeEmail and clientEmail were created by me for test purposes

Comment: Still if you are home your may still be behind a firewall.  You are missing the FROM property which is required and has to be the same as the email account.

Comment: im using the FROM property, its the employeeEmail, and yes, im using the same email as the email account

Comment: Either the credentials are wrong, the FROM is not matching the account, or you are working inside the company firewall.  Sometimes errors occur if the send (not sent) mail box is full.

Comment: @DC What is the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @jdweng i've triple checked the variables and they all match and are the correct ones. Also, the mail box is empty, both from the employeeEmail and the clientEmail

Comment: @RahulSharma The only thing that comes up in the output is "Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.Net.Mail.dll", nothing else

Comment: @DC Place your entire method inside `try-catch` block. Write your catch block like this: `catch(Exception ex){return ex.ToString();}`. Once you do this, then tell us what is the stack trace after invoking this method?

Comment: It should be very simple to find.  GMAIL uses port 587 with SSL and your code look fine.   I would try sending a message with no body to check if the body is good.

Comment: @RahulSharma ok, there it is-  "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   ...

Comment: ... at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at BLL.ClassBLL.SendEmail(String employeeEmail, String clientEmail, String subject, String message)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the exception that you are getting, you have to enable Less Secure Sign-In (or Less secure app access) in your google account.

After sign into google account, go to:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
or
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

and enable the option. Once you do this step, you should be able to send e-mails.

Comment: My god... i really though this was already allowed since i've allowed it before but it wasnt.
Thank you very much, i've been stuck here for days.

Comment: Also, i think that with this implementation, i can only send emails from gmail to gmail. Is there any way i can send emails from gmail, to another domains such as hotmail for example ?

Comment: No, you can send emails to any domain using this. Also don't forget to up-vote if the solution was helpful for you.

Comment: ok, i tried and yes, it sends to different domains aswell. Thank you so much